# CoreData versioning - how often do I need to add version?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

Let's say I create a new version of my model today and I add some properties to my model.  In a couple of days I need to add a few more properties, do I then need to create another version of my model?  For each individual change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While developing I would not recommend to add a new version for each change.
You would end up with far to many versions soon.

Creating a new version for each public release of your software should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Agree with this. Also take care that when you do publicly release that your model is as correct as you can make it. You might even wish to add reserved generic properties . Data migration can be a pain in CoreData

Comment: +1 There is no reason to use versioning during development. Just delete the old persistent store and start fresh every time you modify the model. You only need versioning for shipping versions because versioning is only used in migrating and merging an existing persistent store with the new model.